# igdumdx32.dll APPCRASH

Tags: windows-7, dll

I have a problem with GTA San Andreas. It crashes after loading and this APPCRASH box pop-ups:

*Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: gta_sa.exe
  Application Version: 0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp: 427101ca
  Fault Module Name: igdumdx32.dll
  Fault Module Version: 8.15.10.2993
  Fault Module Timestamp: 5109adce
  Exception Code: c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00013d4f
  OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID: 1033
  Additional Information 1: d68b
  Additional Information 2: d68bd3b8282f5e72182bbd7e42e4d6c7
  Additional Information 3: 6c49
  Additional Information 4: 6c49d494190589b8dc6d7b57ccb74dfb*

The Laptop is new with all updated drivers. GTA San Andreas works fine on old laptop. Help Needed.

Comment: Are you sure the Intel graphics driver is up do date? Is GTA San Andreas up to date?

Answer (score 0):

Igdumd32.dll is a process belonging to the Intel Graphics Accelerator Drivers for Windows 7.
The video card driver on the computer needs to be updated.
Refer the below link to Intel download center download and install the latest driver update for the graphics card on the computer and check if the issue is fixed.

http://downloadcenter.intel.com/

If problem still exists, you may need to configure switchable graphics. Some user fixed their similar problem by this way, check this link below for assistance. If your laptop uses NVIDIA graphics, operation should be similar.

http://forum.bioware.com/topic/270920-igdumd32dll-appcrash/

In addition, run your GTA 3 under the compatibility mode to see the result.

Regards